# Can we use a 0 when we have the datatype as varchar2 in Oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm using a case statement and if the value is true then it should return a field value and with concat of - 0.

But when i'm running it i'm getting the output as  field value - Null instead i need it as Field value - 0

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Not able to replicate your issue. Maybe it's your editor display. Perhaps just change -0 to '-0'.

Comment: Please include an example of your actual CASE statement.

Comment: add data & code

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```sql
WITH test_tab AS
    (   Select 123 "COL_NUMERIC", To_Date('01.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "COL_DATE", '123' "COL_VARCHAR"  From Dual        )
--  ----------------------
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN To_Char(COL_NUMERIC) || ' - 0' END "COL_NR",
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN To_Char(COL_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ' - 0' END "COL_DT",
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN COL_VARCHAR || ' - 0' END "COL_CH"
FROM
    test_tab
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  COL_NR  COL_DT         COL_CH
--  ------- -------------- -------
--  123 - 0 01.01.2022 - 0 123 - 0
```